# Check ApostropheCMS logged in user in PHP page

Tags: apostrophe-cms

i've integrated (under the same site) an iframe to load a php page in an ApostropheCMS content.
The user login into apostrophe and access to that page.

I'd like to be sure, in php page, that the user is really logged in Apostrophe...is it possible to check this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to generally pass data through the iframe. There are lots of resources that cover that.

There is a session ID cookie that is used to identify the user, but then the work to see if they're logged in happens on the server. So in your template you could look for `data.user` exists (`{% if data.user %}{% endif %}`). If it does, then someone is logged in and you can set a data attribute or other markup to help pass correct information through the iframe.

There might be situations where you want to make sure they have certain permissions as well, which you can find on that object.

Comment: first of all, thanks! But the control your hint is on apostrophe server side...can i check anything by PHP side ? obviously all is behind the same reverse proxy...thanks again

Comment: One way or another I think the Apostrophe page would need to send information about the user into the iframe. Either through `window.postMessage()` or as a query parameter on the iframe URL.